How to get 95% confidence interval with table1
I am using R markdown and simulating the scenario with table1 package on the melanoma data set.
is there a way to get for the continuous variables 95% confidence interval written in this way [lower CI, upper CI] below the mean and SD values, in the my render
library(boot) 

melanoma2 <- melanoma
 
# Factor the basic variables that
# we're interested in

    melanoma2$status <- 
      factor(melanoma2$status, 
             levels=c(2,1,3),
             labels=c("Alive", # Reference
                      "Melanoma death", 
                      "Non-melanoma death"))

    labels <- list(
        variables=list(sex="Sex",
                       age="Age (years)",
                       ulcer="Ulceration",
                       thickness="Thicknessᵃ (mm)"),
        groups=list("", "", "Death"))

# Remove the word "death" from the labels, since it now appears above

    levels(melanoma2$status) <- c("Alive", "Melanoma", "Non-melanoma")

    strata <- c(list(Total=melanoma2), split(melanoma2, melanoma2$status))

    my.render.cont <- function(x) {
        with(stats.apply.rounding(stats.default(x), digits=2), c("",
            "Mean (SD)"=sprintf("%s (&plusmn; %s)", MEAN, SD)))
    }
    my.render.cat <- function(x) {
        c("", sapply(stats.default(x), function(y) with(y,
            sprintf("%d (%0.0f %%)", FREQ, PCT))))

}


not familiar with this package, but could you do something like sprintf("%s (&plusmn; %s)<br />%s - %s", MEAN, SD, LOWER, UPPER)

No, Not really. Doesnot work
